Is this proof of the linear convergence of Newton's method correct?
$\require{cancel}$
Newton's root finding method has at least quadratic convergence rate when used to find a simple root $x^*$ of a function $f(x)$ (by simple root I mean that $f(x^*)=0$, but every derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x^*$ is non-zero).
However, if $x^*$ has multiplicity $m>1$, then the convergence rate becomes linear.
Let $g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. I know that, if $g'(x)\neq 0$ (which implies that $x^*$ is not a simple root), then the following result holds:
$$\displaystyle{\lim_{k\to + \infty}\frac{|x_{k+1}-x^*|}{|x_k-x^*|}}=|g'(x^*)|<1$$
this means that the convergence rate is linear (even though I have no clue about where this result comes from).
I tried to give a proof to show that the convergence rate is, indeed, linear when $x^*$ is a root of multiplicity greater than $1$.
My proof
Using Taylor's expansion, i rewrite $f(x)$ as
$$f(x)=f(x^*)+f'(x^*)(x-x^*)+\frac{f''(x^*)}{2!}(x-x^*)^2+\dots+\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}(x-x^*)^m+\dots$$
Since $x^*$ has multiplicity $m$, the first $m$ terms are equal to zero
$$f(x)=\cancel{f(x^*)}+\cancel{f'(x^*)(x-x^*)}+\cancel{\frac{f''(x^*)}{2!}(x-x^*)^2}+\dots+\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}(x-x^*)^m+\dots$$
$$f(x)= \frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}\cdot (x-x^*)^m+O((x-x^*)^m)$$
It's first derivative is
$$f'(x)=\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}\cdot m(x-x^*)^{m-1}+O((x-x^*)^m)$$
Now, substituting these expressions into Newton's iteration formula:
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}=x_k-\frac{{\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}}\cdot (x_k-x^*)^m+{O((x_k-x^*)^m)}}{{\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}}\cdot m(x_k-x^*)^{m-1}+{O((x_k-x^*)^m)}}$$
As $x_k\to x^*$, the term $O((x_k-x^*)^m)$ becomes negligible
$$x_{k+1}\approx x_k-\frac{\cancel{\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}}\cdot (x_k-x^*)^m+\cancel{O((x_k-x^*)^m)}}{\cancel{\frac{f^{(m)}(x^*)}{m!}}\cdot m(x_k-x^*)^{m-1}+\cancel{O((x_k-x^*)^m)}}$$
$$x_{k+1}\approx x_k-\frac{(x_k-x^*)^m}{m(x_k-x^*)^{m-1}}$$
$$x_{k+1}\approx x_k-\frac{(x_k-x^*)}{m}$$
$$x_{k+1}-x^*\approx x_k-x^*-\frac{(x_k-x^*)}{m}$$
$$e_{k+1}\approx e_{k}-\frac{e_{k}}{m}$$
Where $e_{k}$ is the error $(x_k-x^*)$ at step $k$, and $e_{k+1}$ is the error at step $k+1$
$$e_{k+1}\approx e_{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)$$
$$|e_{k+1}|\approx |e_{k}|\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right) \quad \square$$
The result seems correct. Also, it makes sense that, as $m$ grows, the convergence rate becomes slower but remains linear. I'm not so sure about the whole process though. Is the result correct? Does the proof contain errors? Thank you.

It is correct, the big O should be $O(|x-x^{\ast}|^{m+1})$ in the numerator.
